# How to delete empty first column of text file before reading into R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge text file that came with an empty first column but it came with a column header. I was told not to delete the column header manually because this text file is used by another application. I can't show it because I am not able to read it in R. I have heard about colClasses but couldn't make it work. I also tried `fread` from `data.table` with no luck. Here is a small example of what I am talkin about:

[image]

I want to delete the first column with a and a.
I have tried this:

```
require(data.table) 
pp <- fread("myfile.txt", drop = 1)
head(pp)
```

but get an error:
Warning message:
In fread("myfile.txt,', drop = 1) :
Stopped early on line 3. Expected 524 fields but found 523.
Thanks beforehand.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a better reproducible example. I was able to read my dataset into R using `pp <- fread("myfile.txt", skip = 1)` but my column names shifted right and now my last column is filled with NA's. How can I delete the `a` column name and shift left all my column names without the NA's?
Here is a snapshot and dput of a few records:

```
    a year   fday  first    sec third
1: 1998    1 21.633 21.535 21.481    NA
2: 1998    2 21.146 20.936 20.838    NA
3: 1998    3 20.725 20.651 20.599    NA
4: 1998    4 20.716 20.653 20.620    NA
5: 1998    5 19.606 19.493 19.459    NA
6: 1998    6 18.501 18.314 18.231    NA

pp <- structure(list(a = c(1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L
), year = 1:6, fday = c(21.633, 21.146, 20.725, 20.716, 19.606, 
18.501), first = c(21.535, 20.936, 20.651, 20.653, 19.493, 18.314
), sec = c(21.481, 20.838, 20.599, 20.62, 19.459, 18.231), third = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x05f82498>)

The final dataset should look like this:
   year   fday  first    sec third
1: 1998    1 21.633 21.535 21.481    
2: 1998    2 21.146 20.936 20.838    
3: 1998    3 20.725 20.651 20.599    
4: 1998    4 20.716 20.653 20.620    
5: 1998    5 19.606 19.493 19.459    
6: 1998    6 18.501 18.314 18.231
```

Comment: For your *"I can't show it because I am not able to read it in R"*, I think we get the point, but if this is a real problem in the future you can always paste the top `n` rows of the raw file itself (not using R) or you can post the output from `readLines("myfile.txt",n=10)`. Both will show the raw form of the file, typically a better thing anyway when a question is about how to read it in.

Comment: @r2evans-- I couldn't do that either because my dataset has 763 columns. I am posting a reproducible example shortly.

Comment: I understand, and thank you for trying to keep it brief. However, it looks like you generated a small dataset for the image of data, and it looks like it is in excel or some other spreadsheet. In that case, you could easily subset the data to the first 5 columns and 5 rows, save that as a csv, and then paste that into a code block here. One impetus for this is that an image of data requires that we transcribe your data, which is generally discouraged. It is not impossible, but with many questions doing it, relying on that tends to slow down or preclude people from attempting answers.

Comment: r2evans thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my post with a small reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Given that the parsing is not going as intended even with `skip=1`, it seems more useful now to include raw text. If you are willing to go to a console (shell prompt), do this: `head myfile.txt | cut -d, -f1-8` and paste the output into a code block here, this should provide the top 10 lines and up to 8 columns, reducing your large data significantly. (It may also indicate problems you don't know you have :-)

Comment: If you're running windows, both of those utilities are found in Rtools (and git-bash and WSL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have the data that you need but the columns are jumbled up?

Try this -

```
#Rename column 1 to n-1
names(pp)[-ncol(pp)] <- names(pp)[-1]
#Drop the last column.
pp[[ncol(pp)]] <- NULL
pp

#   year fday  first    sec  third
#1: 1998    1 21.633 21.535 21.481
#2: 1998    2 21.146 20.936 20.838
#3: 1998    3 20.725 20.651 20.599
#4: 1998    4 20.716 20.653 20.620
#5: 1998    5 19.606 19.493 19.459
#6: 1998    6 18.501 18.314 18.231
```

Comment: It works like a charm!!!!. I have been wrestling with this issue for a couple of days. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
pp <- data.table::fread("myfile.txt",skip=1)
```

Comment: I thought skip=1 only applies to rows. I will try that.

Comment: You can also use `skip="first"` (meaning to skip until you see the string `"first"` on the line). Both skip the first mostly-empty row.